# Using libmpdclient-dev in C++ returns collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I want to use `libmpdclient-dev` in my C++ program. I installed it on my system.

Under `/usr/include/mpd` I found all the header files.

My test program looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<mpd/client.h>

using namespace std;

struct mpd_connection *conn;

int main() {
    conn = mpd_connection_new("192.168.1.151", 6600, 0);

    if(conn == NULL) {
        cout << "Not connected \n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Connected \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

It compiles fine:

```
g++ -g  -Wfatal-errors  -std=c++11 main.cpp -c -o main.o
```

---

However, running the linker as follows:

```
g++ -g  -Wfatal-errors  -std=c++11 main.o -o run
```

---

gives this error:

```
main.o: In Function `main':
~/mpd/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `mpd_connection_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What do I need to add or change to link successfully?

Comment: Installing the library is not enough, you need to link explicitely to the installed library. Probably with something like this: `g++ -g  -Wfatal-errors  -std=c++11 -lmpdclient-dev main.o -o run`, or `g++ -g  -Wfatal-errors  -std=c++11  /usr/include/mpd/libmpdclient-dev.a main.o -o run`

Comment: thank you for your help. -lmpdclient made it working